# Unable to use modulo with pow() in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm writing a program and have been stuck in this part for quite some time.

```
int y;
y = 111 % pow(10,2);
printf("%d",y);
```

The error shown is `invalid operands of types 'int' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'`.

Is there any workaround to this (i.e. using the `pow()` function)?

Comment: Try `(10 * 10)` instead (`pow(10, 2)` is a value of type `double`: you can't do 42 modulus 3.14159). Maybe even do `int square(int n) { return n*n; }`

Comment: `10 * 10`. Using `pow()` to square a number is massive overkill.

Comment: In case you're forced to use the function `pow` (for practice purposes), you need to typecast from double to integer: `y = 111 % ((int)pow(10,2));`.

Comment: @ssd: bad as pow could return 99 due to truncation. more like `(int)round(pow(10,2))`

Comment: @Shawn sure but much less than `pow(1,2)` to compute 1.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: You're right but this can be a decent workaround (though not sure 100%): `y = 111 % ((int)(pow(10,2)+0.5f));`

Comment: yes, that works

Comment: @ssd: No that's a really bad habit to get into. There's an infamous Java bug caused by using the truncation of  `0.5 + f` rather than `round(f)`. But yes, it would work in this case.

Comment: `%` only works with integral operands (`int`, `unsigned`, etc).   Not floating point.  `pow()` returns `double` - a floating point type.   Look up the function `fmod()` which is declared in `<math>` for a relevant floating point function.

Comment: "Is there any workaround to this (i.e. using the pow() function)?" --> Yes.  "Is there a **good** work-around using the pow()" --> No.   Use integer math operators and functions instead of `double` ones like `pow()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831349/2410359).

Comment: Anjishnu, Please tell us why you want to use `pow()` here.

Answer (score 9):

In C, `pow` returns a `double` irrespective of the types of the input parameters.

And a `double` cannot be used as an argument to `%`.

Hence the compiler issues an error.

The solution is to use `10 * 10` rather than using `pow` to raise a number to its second power. Note that because `%` has the same precedence as `*` you'd need to write the expression as `111 % (10 * 10)`.

Answer (score -1):

`pow` actually returns a `double`, on which the modulus operator `%` cannot operate.

Try using the `fmod` method (declared in `math.h`) instead.

Comment: Although `fmod()` will deal with the compiler error, the use of floating-point math to an integer problem unnecessarily opens up code failures due to possible imprecision (of `pow()`) and rounding issues (`double` --> `int`).